# count repeated keys in a dict

Tags: python

I have a dict like this :

```
newdict ={'category': 'failure', 'week': '1209', 'stat': 'tdc_ok', 'severityDue': '2_critic', 'category': 'failure', 'week': '1210', 'stat': 'tdc_nok', 'severityDue': '2_critic'}
```

I want to count the `stat` key by `week`,
I have tried this :

```
 >>> counterdict = defaultdict(Counter)
 >>> for i in newdict :
         counterdict[int(newdict['week'])][newdict['stat']]+=1
```

But I get this result :

```
   [(1210, Counter({'tdc_nok': 12}))]
```

I don't understand why `12` and why is it only the last week?

How can I do this please?

Comment: Hint: print `newdict` straight after you've assigned it... you may be surprised...

Comment: A dictionary has to have unique keys. Are you sure they are not getting overwritten in your code?

Comment: I don't understand the question, could you give some more context?

Comment: Your data structure is wrong. Looks like you need a list of dictionaries. You cannot repeat keys in a dictionary.

Comment: Your actual `newdict` object, as posted here, only contains *4* keys (only *one* each of the duplicate keys actually remain in the final object), so whatever `newdict` *really* is, it is not what you posted here.

Answer (score 3):

You loop over your dictionary keys, then count the *same keys* that many times. There is nothing dynamic about your loop body:

```
counterdict[int(newdict['week'])][newdict['stat']]+=1
```

If you have 12 keys in your dictionary, the above line is executed 12 times.

If you expected to see your loop access *multiple* keys with the same name, you misunderstood how dictionaries work. Dictionaries map *unique* keys to values. Specifying a key more than once in a literal dictionary declaration will result in a dictionary with only *one* copy of each key, with *one* of their values:

```
>>> {'foo': 'bar', 'foo': 'baz'}
{'foo': 'baz'}
```

In CPython, the compiler gives you the *last* value per key defined, which is why you see `'week': '1210'` in your example dictionary.

Your sample input dictionary ends up with only four unique keys:

```
>>> newdict ={'category': 'failure', 'week': '1209', 'stat': 'tdc_ok', 'severityDue': '2_critic', 'category': 'failure', 'week': '1210', 'stat': 'tdc_nok', 'severityDue': '2_critic'}
>>> newdict
{'category': 'failure', 'week': '1210', 'stat': 'tdc_nok', 'severityDue': '2_critic'}
>>> len(newdict)
4
```

which makes me suspect you ran your loop 3 times to come to a count of 12 (looping over the dictionary gives you 4 keys).

If you have an actual *list* of dictionaries, then take each separate dictionary from that list and use that as the basis of your count:

```
for d in list_of_dictionaries:
    counterdict[int(d['week'])][d['stat']] += 1
```

where `list_of_dictionaries` could be:

```
[
    {'category': 'failure', 'week': '1209', 'stat': 'tdc_ok', 'severityDue': '2_critic'},
    {'category': 'failure', 'week': '1210', 'stat': 'tdc_nok', 'severityDue': '2_critic'},
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the dict you give is wrong. A dict has duplicated keys will be overridden. Your dict is actually this:

```
>>> newdict
{'category': 'failure', 'week': '1210', 'stat': 'tdc_nok', 'severityDue': '2_critic'}
```

I think what you want is something like this:

```
>>> newdict =[{'category': 'failure', 'week': '1209', 'stat': 'tdc_ok', 'severityDue': '2_critic'}, {'category': 'failure', 'week': '1210', 'stat': 'tdc_nok', 'severityDue': '2_critic'}]
```

And the loop you give is meaingless. It doesn't do any loop and keeps operators on the same elements.

```
>>> a = defaultdict(Counter)
>>> for item in newdict:
...     a[int(item['week'])][item['stat']] += 1
... 
>>> a
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {1209: Counter({'tdc_ok': 1}), 1210: Counter({'tdc_nok': 1})})
>>>
```